# How to pdfjam by Filename Numbering?

Tags: command-line, wildcards, pdf

My files

```
masi1.jpg
masi2.jpg
masi3-1.jpg
masi4.jpg
...
masi10.jpg
masi11.jpg
...
```

Command `pdfjam *.jpg`. Output: random. Expected output: as the list. 
There is no parameters in `man pdfjam`, only synapsis

```
pdfjam [OPTION [OPTION] ...] [SRC [PAGESPEC] [SRC [PAGESPEC]] ...]
```

- System: Ubuntu 16.04.
- Pdfjam: 2.08.

Comment: you should be getting the alphabetical order `1 10 11... 2 20 ...`. You should try `masi?.jpg masi??.jpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard matches are sorted in lexicographic order, so `10` is between `1` and `2`, not after `9`.

To sort matches with numbers in numeric order, use [zsh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zsh) and its [`n` glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)

```
pdfjam *.jpg(on)
```

Or (still zsh-only) set the `numeric_glob_sort` option:

```
setopt numeric_glob_sort   # this can go in your ~/.zshrc
pdfjam *.jpg
```

If all your files have a number of the same format, you can enumerate the number of digits:

```
pdfjam masi?.jpg masi??.jpg
```

But with fancier file names mixed in like `masi3-1.pdf`, there's no easy solution in bash.